# Print current value of missing variables during manual testing - Clarity Smart Contract

Tags: stack, blockchain, smartcontracts, clarity-lang, stacks-blockchain

Is it possible to print the current value of variables during manual testing to see how they are behaving?

I mean during manual testing in the clarinet console
or do I have to add something like (ok variable_name) at the end of the function?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `print` function for this: https://docs.stacks.co/docs/clarity/language-functions#print